# LUKS full disk encryption with decryption key on USB drive

Tags: redhat, luks, disk-encryption, rhel9

I have alma9 setup with luks full disk encryption. I want to put a decryption key on a usb drive to boot up without a password.

Picking through the various tutorials (mostly for debian), I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

luks_key_filename="luks-key"
usb_name="/dev/sdb"
usb_device="/dev/sdb1"
usb_mount_point="/mnt/usb"
luks_key_file="$usb_mount_point/$luks_key_filename"

# Create a single partition on USB drive
echo -e "o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nt\n83\nw" | fdisk $usb_name
echo "y" | mkfs.ext4 $usb_device
mkdir -p $usb_mount_point
mount $usb_device $usb_mount_point

dd if=/dev/urandom of=$luks_key_file bs=512 count=4

usb_uuid=$(blkid -s UUID -o value $usb_device)

luks_uuid=$(lsblk | grep -o "luks-[a-A0-9-]*" | grep -E -o "[a-Z0-9]{8}[a-Z0-9-]*")
luks_device=$(blkid -t UUID="$luks_uuid" | cut -d':' -f1)
cryptsetup luksAddKey $luks_device $usb_mount_point/$luks_key_filename
```

This seems fairly straight forward.  Now I need to get the USB drive to mount and LUKS to read my key.  I've tried it a couple different ways.

I'm trying to mount the USB and then get crypttab to read it with this:

```
cat > /bin/mount-usb.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p $usb_mount_point
mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/$usb_uuid $usb_mount_point
EOF
chmod +x /bin/mount-usb.sh

cat > /etc/dracut.conf.d/mount-usb.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
check() {
    return 0
}

depends() {
    return 0
}

install() {
    inst_hook pre-mount 00 "/bin/mount-usb.sh"
}
EOF
dracut -f
echo "luks-$luks_uuid UUID=$luks_uuid $usb_mount_point/$luks_key_filename luks,discard" > /etc/crypttab
dracut -f
```

`/var/log/messages` shows that `$luks_key_filename` was not found, so it appears to be looking for it, but `/mnt/usb` is not mounted when I boot.

Am I even on the right track here?  Has anyone solved this?  It appears there's a solution that is not available for viewing: access.redhat.com/solutions/256833

Comment: The viable idea is to intergrate key into the initramfs and install bootloader, kernel and initramfs onto removable media and setup boot only from removable. There'll be no boot partition and ESP on the server's internal storage, so setup them as "noauto" in the fstab. Once server had booted past initramfs loading, remove the boot media. You have to make and maintain at least two copies of this boot media. I successfully used this technique in production with Debian-based Proxmox VE, so I can't give you instructions tailored for RHEL-like.

Comment: I intend to setup a dozen or so machines, and I'd like to have 1 USB key that I can plug in, boot up the machine, then unplug and plug it into the next machine.  Currently, I really need to get the USB to boot pre-decryption.  I should at least be able to get that working.  I was hoping this was a solved problem that someone could just post, but I'll deep dive on the various concepts before I give up on it.  We'll see.